# How to use @Preview with compose function that takes a param?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I have such an implementation:

```
...

    @Composable
    private fun PhoneVerificationCodeScreen(vm: MyViewModel) {
        Column(...) {
...
            OTPBlock(numberOfCells = NUMBER_OF_OTP_CELLS, isVerifyBtnEnabledState = vm.isVerifyBtnEnabledState)
...
        }
    }

...
```

There is my preview function:

```
    class MyViewModelProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<MyViewModel> {
        override val values: Sequence<MyViewModel> = sequenceOf(MyViewModel(
            SavedStateHandle()
        ))
    }

    @Preview(
        name = "Phone-portrait",
        device = Devices.PHONE,
        showBackground = true,
        backgroundColor = 0x111,
        showSystemUi = true
    )
    @Composable
    private fun PhonePreviewVerificationCodeScreen(
        @PreviewParameter(MyViewModelProvider::class) vm: MyViewModel
    ) = PhoneVerificationCodeScreen(vm = vm)
```

SPOILER: before I included ViewModel as a param it worked as expected.

I went through a few solutions in the google and the last one I tried was by using `PreviewParameterProvider`, however, it doesn't work as well.

So, the question is - how to "preview" the compose function that takes a param?

ERROR is:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my_package.VerificationCodeViewModelProvider   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass  at java.lang.Class.forName0  at java.lang.Class.forName  at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposableInvoker.invokeComposable

Comment: Not an answer, but a question, so posting this as a comment, why would you need a view model to create the UI only? What kind of data does the viewModel provide that cannot be hardcoded (to see the UI, without the view model, for design purposes) and then replaced by the VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method recommended on the Android developers site for creating previews of composables with ViewModels is to create an inner composable that accepts the ViewModel parameters as arguments:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyComposable(viewModel: MyViewModel) {

    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    MyComposable(
        state = state
    ) 
}

@Composable
fun MyComposable(state: MyState) {
   ...
}
```

Then create a preview for the inner composable:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun MyComposablePreview(state: MyState = MyState()) {
    MyComposable(state = state)
}
```

See: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/previews#preview-viewmodel

There are various other methods as well, such as using an interface and creating a preview instance of the interface.

Comment: I see your idea, however, in my case `viewModel.arg` is a `State`, so does it mean that it would be necessary to create another function for this one as well?

Comment: Updated the example, something like that should work

Comment: You should not give a state<MyState> to AnotherComposable but only the value of the state to follow state hoisting best practices https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting?hl=en#viewmodels-as-state-owner

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you are looking for but I'd extract the viewmodel from the composables, so instead of this:

```
@Composable
MyComposable(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    Button(onClick = { 
        viewModel.buttonClicked()
    }) {
        Text(text = viewModel.state.myText)
    }
}
```

It'd be something like this

```
val viewModel: YourViewModel = viewModel()
val state: MyState = viewModel.state

@Composable
MyComposable(
    state: MyState,
    onViewEvent: (MyViewEvents) -> Unit,
) {
    Button(onClick = { 
        onViewEvent(MyViewEvents.buttonClicked)
    }) {
        Text(text = state.myText)
    }
}
```

This also allows you to make any number of previews with different states.

Comment: I think that this is the actual answer. You should avoid passing a whole ViewModel into a Composable. Instead, only pass in the actually required values as input or functions as callback. This makes `@Preview` easier to use and also is great for testability.